# how to sort a list of arrays it based on multiple columns

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I want to sort arrays having numerous rows stored in a list based on three columns. I always have four-row arrays. I tried sorting, to arrange my list as described in the following. In the first row, I want to have very low values (something like the min) the min of all columns. In the the second row, first and third column are very low  (something like the min) while the second column is very high(something like the max). The main difference of the first two rows is the second column and in the second row it is remarkably higher than first row. For the third one all columns are meeting their very high values (values that are close to their max values). Regarding the last row, I can say  the main difference of the third and fourth row is again the second column and it is very high (almost max) in the third row but very low (almost min) in the fourth row. Sometimes, the row that has min of first and third column, has not min of second column and this is why I say something like max.
This is my list (for simplicity I presented only two arrays):

```
subset =  [array([[18.93806458, 0.75, 1.],
          [18.75559425, 29.25, 1.],
          [63.2792244, 0.75, 99.],
          [63.5401268, 29.25, 99.]]),  
          array([[58.92893982, 0.75, 99.],
          [59.02889633, 29.25, 99.],
          [13.97888088, 0.75, 1.],
          [13.69346333, 29.25, 1.]])]
```

Then, I want to have the following list which is a pure 3-dimensional list rather than a list of two numpy  2-dimensional arrays:

```
final_subset = [[[18.93806458, 0.75, 1.],
                 [18.75559425, 29.25, 1.],
                 [63.5401268, 29.25, 99.]
                 [63.2792244, 0.75, 99.]],
                [[13.97888088, 0.75, 1.],
                 [13.69346333, 29.25, 1.],
                 [59.02889633, 29.25, 99.],
                 [58.92893982, 0.75, 99.]]]
```

I tried the following code but it was not successful (the first reason was that I did not know how to execute the sorting result on `subset` and save it as `final_subset`):

```
for i in subset:
    i=np.sort(i.view('i8,i8,i8'), order=['f2', 'f1'], axis=0).view(np.float)
    i[[2,3]]=i[[3,2]]
    i=np.array(i)
    i=i.tolist()
```

I truly appreciate any help.

Comment: I don't think the word 'approximate' means the way you think it means. At least to me,  the usage of the word `approximate` in your question do not make sense. Can you find an alternative way to explain it?

Comment: I mean not the exact min or max. In fact, I mean it is low or high, but it may not be exactly the min or max value.